# How to convert a float string to an integer in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-conversion, floating-point-conversion

I'm new to the whole coding thing...so here goes.
Just trying to write a simple number guess game, but also do input validation. So that only integers are accepted as input.  I've figured out how to weed out alphabetic characters, so I can convert the numbers into an integer.  I'm having trouble when I put in a float number.  I can't get it to convert the float number over to an integer.  Any help is appreciated.  As I said I'm on about day 3 of this coding thing so try to be understanding of my little knowledge.  Thanks in advance.

Here's the function from my main program.

```
def validateInput():
    while True:
        global userGuess
        userGuess = input("Please enter a number from 1 to 100. ")
        if userGuess.isalpha() == False:
            userGuess = int(userGuess)
            print(type(userGuess), "at 'isalpha() == False'")
            break
        elif userGuess.isalpha() == True:
            print("Please enter whole numbers only, no words.")
            print(type(userGuess), "at 'isalpha() == True'")
    return userGuess
```

Here's the error I'm getting if I use 4.3 (or any float) as input.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\*******.py\line 58, in <module>
validateInput()
File "C:\\*******.py\line 28, in validateInput
userGuess = int(userGuess)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.3'
```

Comment: You could try to chain your conversions using try-except. If your int() conversion generates a ValueError exception, you could try to convert input using float() and then round or truncate your float value to integer.

Comment: A few side notes: You almost never want to check `if spam == False:`, just `if not spam:`. In an `elif`, you don't need to recheck the opposite of the `if` test—you already _know_ `isalpha` is true, because you know it isn't false. So, just use `else:`. If you're returning `userGuess` from this function, you almost certainly don't need it to be `global`. And finally, you don't need to `break` just to hit the `return`; you can just `return userGuess` right there in the `if` block.

Answer (score 49):

Actually `int()` function expects an **integer string** or a **float**, but not a **float string**. If a float string is given you need to convert it to `float` first then to `int` as:

```
int(float(userGuess))
```

Comment: This does not work for large numbers; for example int(float('8304305552891322054.0')) returns wrong 8304305552891322368 value while int('8304305552891322054') returns 8304305552891322054

Comment: @JalilHamdollahiOskouei This is not a `float()` issue at all but a fundamental limitation of floats with [limited precision for large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values), a core concept of Computer Science. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html. If you need precision of such levels, go with something like [decimal.Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `isalpha` to screen the output.  [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) -- convert it and handle that exception.  Either the `ValueError` is exactly what you want, in that you can handle it and tell the user to correct their input.  Or for some odd reason you want to silently correct their input from "4.3" to "4".

```
def validateInput():
    while True:
        global userGuess
        userGuess = input("Please enter a number from 1 to 100. ")
        try:
            int(userGuess)
            return userGuess # you shouldn't really keep this string...
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Please enter whole numbers only, no words.")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you *want* to convert the float string to an integer? Do you want to treat `4.7` as meaning the user has guessed `4`? Or `5`? Or a legal but automatically-invalid guess? Or as actually the value `4.7` (in which case you don't want integers at all)? Or…?

---

Second, the way you're approaching this is wrong. `userGuess.isalpha()` only tells you that the guess is made entirely of letters. That means you're still going to treat, say, `"Hello!"` as a number, because it has at least one non-letter.

If you want to know if a string is a valid integer, just call `int` on it, and use a `try`/`except` to handle the case where it isn't:

```
def validateInput():
    while True:
        global userGuess
        userGuess = input("Please enter a number from 1 to 100. ")
        try:
            userGuess = int(userGuess)
            print(type(userGuess), "after int succeeeded")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter whole numbers only, no words.")
            print(type(userGuess), "after int failed")
    return userGuess
```

If you want to handle actual words differently from other kinds of failure, e.g., so you can print a more specific error message, then you can check `isalpha` inside the `except` clause.

If you want to handle check whether it's a float so you can give a different error, do the same thing—`try` to call `float(userGuess)`—inside the `except` clause. Or, if you want to truncate floats, change that `int(userGuess)` to `int(float(userGuess))`.

You may also want some other checks even inside the `try` part. For example, what if they type `-23` or `178`? Those are integers, but they're not numbers between 1 and 100.

Obviously, the more validation you want, the more code it takes, because each test is another line of code. So, you may want to consider moving the validation out to a separate function from the looping over input, to make it more readable.

Answer (score -1):

You could use string manipulation and typecasting.

```
int(userGuess.split('.')[0])
```